# sql select where (sum of 2 columns) is greater than X

Tags: sql

I have a dynamic SQL query based on user selections.  2 of the columns (FullBath, HalfBath) need to be counted as one for SELECT operations.  EX: a user searches for a property in a specific town and minimum number of bathrooms (HalfBath and FullBath combined) is greater than or equal to x.

I tried variations of:

SELECT * From Rentals WHERE Town = *town* AND (SUM(FullBath + HalfBath) >= *bathrooms*)

=========================

I found answer (don't need SUM...)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you intending to use aggregation (`GROUP BY`)? The `SUM()` doesn't make sense otherwise, where the arithmetic in `FullBath + HalfBath` will suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Rentals
WHERE Town = Town
AND FullBath + HalfBath >= Bathrooms
```